# In Robinson Crusoe Castaways Scenario, will the hatchet and snare keep after camp has been moved?

Tags: robinson-crusoe

In Robinson Crusoe, players can build a hatchet item in the Castaways scenario to add a +1 wood token to the island tile with their camp.  As long as the camp remains on that island tile, the players will receive one additional wood during the production phase.

Players can also opt to move their camp at night to an adjacent island tile.  There is no mention of what happens to the +1 wood token on the island tile of the previous camp after the players have relocated.

Another token, the shortcut token, that provides an additional resource during the gathering phase, does get removed when the camp is relocated, forcing players to rebuild it.  Do the players, after moving the camp:

- a)  move the +1 wood token from the hatchet,
- b)  lose the +1 wood
  token but keep the hatchet,
- c)  lose the +1 wood token and lose the
  hatchet (forcing rebuild), or
- d)  keep the +1 wood token on the
  previous camp's island tile and let it as act an additional wood
  resource for collection during the gathering phase?

Answer (score 5):

On page 13 of the [rules](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Robinson.pdf), under **Moving the Camp**, it states that

> If there are any +1 resource tokens (as an effect of a built Item) ... you can move [them] with the Camp.

The only limit is that you're only allowed to have a single token per "spot," so if you move your camp with +1 food and +1 wood to a place that already has a +1 food token, you lose the extra +1 food token.

So **keep the tokens, keep your inventions, and move the tokens with the camp.**